# Checking the return value of `isalpha`

Tags: c, isalpha

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char userPassword[20];

    printf("Type in your password: \n");
    scanf("%c", &userPassword);

    if (isalpha(userPassword) == 0) {
        printf("Nice");
    } else {
        printf("Nope");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to come up with a code where to check if the password contains only letters. Why does this code only work with the " == 0" sign. My friend told me to put this and my code works. What does the " == 0" do?

Comment: If you don't want `==0`, try `if(!isalpha(userPassword))`

Comment: You are only reading and testing one char, not a string.

Comment: `isalpha` returns '0' (false) if test fails, otherwise  it returns non-zero(true) if the test passes. So, use '!' as suggested above.

Comment: The line `scanf("%c", &userPassword);` is wrong on multiple accounts.  You read a single character into an array; you pass a pointer to an array where a pointer to a character is expected; you don't don't check the return value from `scanf()`; you're liable to problems with leftover newlines etc after this input.  It isn't clear whether you want 1-character passwords (hint — they're not secure) but then why bother with an array of 20 characters.  (Only 20 characters including null; darn it — there goes my favourite password scheme!)

Comment: Oh, and `isalpha()` expects a single character; you're passing a pointer to it.  The compiler should be complaining.  Don't post non-compiling code unless you state that you can't get it to compile and show what the error messages are.  And make sure that what the code is an MCVE ([MCVE]).

Comment: The code *doesn't* work with that.

Answer (score 2):

The signature of `isalpha` is `int isalpha ( int c )`.

> - **Parameters**
>     c character to classify
> - **Return value**
>     Non-zero value if the character is an alphabetic character, zero otherwise.

So, if `c` is not alpha, it returns non-zero, otherwise 0.

About the program:

1. `scanf` needs `char *`, not `&userPassword`, which is `char **`. `scanf("%s", userPassword)` is OK.
2. pass `char` to `isalpha` instead of `char *`.

If you want to check if a string is all alpha, you can simply iterate the string and check each single character. Like:

```
bool is_all_alpha(char *s) {
    for (; *s!='\0'; ++s) {
        if (!isalpha(*s)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

---

1. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha

Comment: `&userPassword` is `char (*)[20]`, not `char **`